# Android ListView Bind to Custom Class

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-widget, android-listview

I have a Custom ListView created from XML Layout. I want to bind that to my Custom Data Class.
How do i Convert that class to a ListAdapter and bind the layout to the ListView. The Code of the class is as Follows:

```
public class Sessions {

private int status;
private List<Session> sessions;

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public List<Session> getSessions() {
    return sessions;
}

public void setSessions(List<Session> sessions) {
    this.sessions = sessions;
}

public static class Session {
    public Boolean active;
    public String contributor_covu_id;
    public String created_at;
    public String key;
    public String status;
    public String name;
    public String type;
};
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create an Activity based on ListActivity and use something like what's below in your onCreate. It'll make a list with a simple two line layout for each row and set the text to the session name and session status.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final List<Sessions.Session> sessions = new Sessions().getSessions();
    setListAdapter(new BaseAdapter() {

        public int getCount() {
            return sessions.size();
        }

        public Object getItem(int pos) {
            return sessions.get(pos);
        }

        public long getItemId(int pos) {
            return pos;
        }

        public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = View.inflate(ViewTest.this, android.R.layout.two_line_list_item, null);
            }

            Sessions.Session session = (Sessions.Session) getItem(pos);

            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setText(session.name);

            text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);
            text.setText(session.status);
            return view;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

[Simple List Adapter](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2008/03/my-first-meeting-with-simpleadapter.html)

You can search for tutorials on how to make a simple List Adapter. This shows one simple approach of binding your list to an adapter. You can find many others even more advanced examples.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend the ArrayAdapter class. [Here](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/) is a good tutorial that will show you how to override the correct methods (especially the getView() method).